# Replacing front matter elements of a list with site variables

Tags: jekyll, liquid

I am using Jekyll for an academic website. I am using posts with `publication` category to represent publications. A paper that has been written by the latest Presidents of USA, for example, would look similar to this (except for some others variables that are irrelevant to this question):

```
---
categories: publications
layout: publication
title: "This is the paper Title"
authors: [bomama, gwbush, bclinton]
---
```

In particular, I would like elements in the list of authors to translate to some predefined URLs, which could be specified as site variables, for instance. I would like to do this so I don't have to change every publication (=post) when an author changes institution (and, consequently, his/her webpage URL).

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In `_config.yml` you can add your own namespace for user defined variables:

```
app:
  authors:
    bomama:
      name: 'Barack Obama'
      url: 'http://barackobama.com'
    gwbush:
      name: 'George W. Bush'
      url: 'http://georgewbush.com'
```

Then in your template loop over authors and merge in the user defined `app:authors`:

```
{% for id in page.authors %}

  {% if site.app.authors[id] %}
    <a href="{{ site.app.authors[id]['url'] }}">{{ site.app.authors[id]['name'] }}</a>
  {% endif %}

{% endfor %}
```

Outputs:

```
<a href="http://barackobama.com">Barack Obama</a>

<a href="http://georgewbush.com">George W. Bush</a>
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know I could use the `authors[id]` construct.